# Why is no list returned by my function on button click?

Tags: angularjs

Why doesn't this function return a list of profiles?

The server returns a list, but it never gets copied to `$scope.profiles`.

If I remove the `changeTheme` function, then the list is called. (But then it's not in sync with the application.)

I can't find the error in the code.

```
$scope.changeTheme = function (activeTheme) {
    profileRepository.getProfiles(activeTheme).then(
    function (dataResponse) {
        $scope.profiles = dataResponse.data;
        angular.forEach($scope.profiles, function (value, index) {
            if (value.themeCode == "SOC" && value.blacklisted == true) {
                $scope.boolSOCBlacklisted = true;
            } else if (value.themeCode == "DAT" && value.blacklisted == true) {
                $scope.boolDATBlacklisted = true;
            } else if (value.themeCode == "DIR" && value.blacklisted == true) {
                $scope.boolDIRBlacklisted = true;
            }

        })
        $scope.boolProfileLoad = true;
    });
};
```

Comment: maybe you can try using "done" instead of "then"

Comment: what exactly isn't working?  WHat steps have you tried to troubleshoot? We can't help debug without a way to replicate it

Comment: Just tried that and nothing new happend.. I cant find a good example of doing this kind of call to get a list from the server.

Comment: Im new in this, and I dont know have to replecate the code without the complete project. The problem is that the dataResponse dosent get copied to the $scope.profiles list. If im removing the function call (line one and last), then I get the result in a list. It seems like the code in the Then part dosent get called.

Comment: Are you actually calling `changeTheme(activeTheme)` to your directive or inside any controller?

Comment: I calling it with a ng-click="changeTheme(activeTheme = 'SOC')"

Comment: If you are having trouble debugging this in the developer console, remove the forEach call (just for debugging) or try the methods mentioned here http://www.divshot.com/blog/tips-and-tricks/ignoring-library-code-while-debugging-in-chrome/

Comment: I have tried cooment out the foreach and console.log. The problem is that it newer reach that code..